# What is most efficient query for value range in MongoDB

Tags: java, mongodb

I gather MongoDB uses binary trees for field indices, so to get a range should be possible to find the first lower, then iterate through the index to the upper limit and quit.

They have their query filters where you can compose all sorts of logic operations and was wondering if any filter or query operation combination will cause the above optimization to happen when the filter is applied to the data on the server.

A way to specify a "within range" filter which if applied first will quit before invoking a more random filter in a logic graph.  That is the search on the server is optimized only to traverse the desired initially specified range.

```
value = findAbove(min);
while( value > start) {
    if(value >= max) {
        break;
    }
    if(filterGraph.matches(value) addToOutput(value);
    value = nextAbove(value);
} 
replyWithOutput(output);
```

What query spec might cause a specified filter graph to be "compiled" so this optimization is done on the server? This is important in my case because the set is very large and the range is small.

Comment: What are the terms you are using - "filter chain", "compiled"? To see how the server executes your queries, use the explain functionality.

Comment: In general, [range queries](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/index.html#query-for-ranges) are optimized to use indexes .

Comment: @prasad_  I would assume so but there is no range query I have found in the documentation only composing their filters with an lt or lte and a gt or gte filter. and wondering if their filter "compiler" will perform such an optimization especially if placed logically before subsequent filters.  Or if they have a special way of specifying such a filter that guarantees that sort of optimization.

Comment: @D.SM  filter chain stands for a coded bunch of filters assembled into a graph (their Filter items) 

Compiling is like compiling a regex, that is one symbolic representation of the logic is preprocessed before an operation where it will be repeatably used so as to make if more efficient at determining what passes or is rejected by the filter and minimizing the amount of the database that must be accessed via slow means.

Comment: So what does that have to do with MongoDB and queries being sent to it? You should be looking at explains.

Comment: @D.SM what do you mean by "explains" I have read their manual and looked at their samples and searched for public posts.  The only info I see there is to set up the proper indices, and then build queries - I can of course build a large database and profile it and over the wire traffic with various query structures and regexes by trial and error.  My question is if there is an optimal way to structure such queries where it actually does limit the range traversed in a sorted index of a large dataset filtered by their comparison filters or a regex.